# Manipulating regex matches directly in the regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a few regexes in an array and testing some strings against them.

```
$results = array();

$testString = 'The distance is 0,1 km. It is above 200 m.';

$regex = array(
  'distance' => '/The distance is (?P<distance>\d+) m\./',
  'distance' => '/The distance is (?P<distance>\d+(,\d+)?) km\./',
  'height' => '/It is above (?P<height>\d+) m\./'
  'height' => '/It is above (?P<height>\d+(,\d+)?) km\./'
);

foreach ($regex as $key => $reg) {
  if (preg_match($reg, $testString, $matches)) {
    $results[] = array('type' => $key, 'value' => $matches[$key]);
  }
}
```

I want to store the results as "meters", but in the test string above, the "km"-regex is matched.

Can I add some magic to the regex code, so it transforms the matched `0,1` into `100` (= match * 1000)?

It would be perfect to do it right in the regex code, so I dont have to add exceptions into the PHP code.

Thank you for your help! :)

Wulf

Comment: Are you trying to do unit conversion here? Or not, since 0,1 km = 100 m?

Comment: In this case I'm trying to make the 0,1 km to 100 m, so the match in the end is `100` and not `0,1`. Corrected the typo in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dirty tricks, you could do something like this after assigning the string:

```
$testString = preg_replace('/(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?(\s*)km\b/e', '($1.$2 * 1000)."$3m"', $testString);
```

http://ideone.com/Sk2um

**PS**: you can't do that directly in your regex (in PHP anyway), you have to use some code somewhere for it  to work.

**Explanation**: It matches numbers with `km` after them, capturing the integer and decimal parts, then replacing them with the results of the PHP code in the replacement:

```
(<integer>.<decimal> * 1000)."<space>m"
```

The code is evaluated because the `/e` flag is used.

Comment: This is great. I don't get how it works, could you please explain how the replace parameter calculates the new value directly inline?

But I will use your solution, it works great for my case. Thank you!

Comment: Wulf: Added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get how 0,1 would equate to 1000. But in case you are looking for replacing based on a regular expression, check this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php . For a simple substitution you can use preg_replace but I can't figure out the logic behind your conversion.

Comment: It was a typo, I mean 100 of course. But I am looking for a solution directly in the regex code, f.e. `(?P<distance>\d+(,/d+)?{,=.|*1000})`

Comment: I just read your comment. If you are using , instead of the decimal point this regex would work `preg_replace('/The distance is (\d+), (\d+) km\./', strval(floatval($1 . '.' . $2)*1000), $testString)`

Comment: Wulf: Even if you could, PHP will not multiply `1,2` for you, since it uses `.` as a decimal separator, not `,`.

Comment: Qtax: Thats why I added to my "pseudocode" a `,=.` (replace `,` in the match with `.`) and then `*1000` (multiply the match with 1000).

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think you could add such logic to a regular expression. I would instead change your regex so it matches out the value `(\d+(,\d+)?)` and the unit `(m|km)`. Then convert the value to float using something like

```
$value = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $value));
```

Depending on what the unit is you can normalize this value to meters

```
case ($unit) {
  case 'km':
    $value *= 1000;
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a direct `regex` solution, but just doing what you need

```
$results = array();

$testString = 'The distance is 0,1 km. It is above 200 m.';

$regex = array(
  'distance' => '/The distance is (?P<distance>\d+) (?P<unit>m)\./',
  'distance' => '/The distance is (?P<distance>\d+(,\d+)?) (?P<unit>km)\./',
  'height' => '/It is above (?P<height>\d+) (?P<unit>m)\./',
  'height' => '/It is above (?P<height>\d+(,\d+)?) (?P<unit>km)\./'
);

foreach ($regex as $key => $reg) {
  if (preg_match($reg, $testString, $matches)) {
    $multiplier = ($matches['unit']=='km')?1000:1;
    $value = str_replace(",",".",$matches[$key]);
    $results[] = array('type' => $key, 'value' => $value*$multiplier);
  }
}
var_dump($results);
```